# A Letter to My Dear Friend

Tags: riddle

> Hello, my most dear friend,
>
> How are you doing,
>
> I know why we are such good friends,
>
> We can be abbreviated by 3 letters,
>
> We can be the go-to and favorite for some people,
>
> There is even a song about **us**,
>
> We can even  *come* together,
>
> I am salty and you are sweet,
>
> I have not seen you in a while since I have been forbidden from some public places,
>
> Some people cannot bear me nor can they come in contact with me,
>
> Yet, we are the best of friends and I hope to see you soon my good friend,
>
> Thanks,
>
> -Your Good Friend

Who is the *speaker* and who is the *recipient* of the letter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this might be a letter

> from **peanut butter** to **jelly**,

because

> 1. They go together in a [popular sandwich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peanut_butter_and_jelly_sandwich) (definitely one of my favorites.), so they're the go-to and favorite of some people -- especially schoolchildren!
>  2. There is a [popular "song"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8MDNFaGfT4) about the time they spend together.
>  3. Peanut butter is usually salty (though without added salt it mostly just tastes nutty). Jelly is always sweet.
>  4. Some schools, which are arguably public places, have apparently [banned peanut butter](https://www.today.com/news/schools-peanut-bans-spark-backlash-wbna26124593)...
>  5. Because some people are [highly allergic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peanut_allergy) to peanuts -- they can't come in contact with it.

Comment: You got it right! :D

Answer (score 5):

Could it be

> Peanut Butter talking to Chocolate?

We can be the go-to and favorite for some people,

> Well, *I,* for one, would call Reese's PB cups my fave...

There is even a song about us,

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Bwdeb_OGhc

We can even come together,

> Oh, *baby!* REESE'S FastBreak, REESE'S Pieces, Peanut Butter Cup Minis...

I am salty and you are sweet,

> Nuts? salty. Chocolate? Sweet!

I have not seen you in a while since I have been forbidden from some public places,

> [image]

Some people cannot bear me nor can they come in contact with me,

> When I was a kid, nobody seemed to have [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peanut_allergy), but now, it's everywhere.

Comment: Sorry not the intended answer but definitely fits, I should have added more fitting answers to "jam". +1